# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ngOriginalError')

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, core-js

I am running a test environment on my local machine for an angular app for my company that I was just hired by. The application has four routes, as it is only targeted by links from an external application. Each of these links are protected by a MsalGuard, which I deactivated so I could see the app without logging in. I am getting the following runtime error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ohAi.png)

I went into core.js in node_modules and ran a console.trace() from there, but the issue is that none of the stack trace is in the src directory, only in node_modules. What should I do in a situation like this?
[Only in node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iJZe.png)

Tried stack trace, did not prove helpful.

Update: I should add that the application is about 4 years old now, and many of the packages in node_modules are deprecated. I suspect that this might be the issue, especially since the stack trace is entirely in node_modules/.